# For each 3 posts, show a different post type

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, count

I would like to do 3 posts of `post_type` "daily" and between them a different `post_type` "quotes"

I would like to do 3 by 3 like for each 3 daily, show a `post_type` "quotes".

How can I do that?~

**UPDATE**

here's the code I have so far
(PREVIOUS QUERY):

```
 query_posts( $new_args );
        if (have_posts()) :
            $count = 0;
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                if ( $count == TRYING_TO_FIGURE_HOW_TO_DO ){
                        $argsQuotes = array(
                                        'post_type'     => 'quotes'
                                    );
                        $queryQuote = new WP_Query ( $argsQuotes );

                        if ( $queryQuote->have_posts() ) :
                            while ( $queryQuote->have_posts() ) :
                                $queryQuote->the_post();

                                echo '<li data-url="' . get_permalink() . '"></li>';

                            endwhile;
                        endif;
                }
                    echo '<li data-url="' . get_permalink() . '"></li>';
                    $count++;
            endwhile;
        endif;
```

I wanna do it 3 by 3 but I can't figure how to do this.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far? Please show in detail what you want to achieve, to increase the change of others understanding the problem. thanks

Comment: I have updated with the code I have so far

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Here's an easy one. Let's say you want to mix 9 'daily' posts and 3 'quotes'. First you would have to [get those posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts):

```
$dailies = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 9, 'post_type' => 'daily'))
$quotes = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type' => 'quote'))
```

Next you would loop through them like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
  // html to output $dailies[$i]
  $j = (($i-2)/3) // will be integer if $i=2, 5, 7, so after three dailies
  if (is_int($j) {
    // html to output $quotes[$j]
    }
  }
```

You will need to add some extra logic to prevent errors in case there are less than 9 or 3 posts respectively.

Comment: i don't think I explained myself so well. Imagine I have a Post Per Page, like outputing a SINGLE.php with post type_daily. I have a Next Page Button. If i click 3 times in the next it outputs a single.php with post_type 'quotes'. And so On.

Comment: That is really quite a different question. It's about navigation: what to show in the Next Page Link. Right?

Comment: It's the same, but the query is different if the $count number is, for example 3, or 7 and so on, if its not it shows the dailies query.

Comment: Except that you would have to keep track of your indexes not on one page, but between several pages. You could use a query_var for that and use an offset when getting the posts.